# Nested text encodings in suds requests

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, character-encoding

Environment: Python 2.7.4 (partly on Windows, partly on Linux, see below), suds (SVN HEAD with minor modifications)

I need to call into a web service that takes a single argument, which is an XML string (yes, I know…), i.e. the request is declared in the WSDL with the following type:

```
<s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="actionString" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I'm using `cElementTree` to construct this inner XML document, then I pass it as the only parameter to the `client.service.ProcessAction(request)` method that suds generates.

For a while, this worked okay:

```
root = ET.Element(u'ActionCommand')
value = ET.SubElement(root, u'value')
value.text = saxutils.escape(complex_value)
request = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n' + ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
client.service.ProcessAction(request)
```

The `saxutils.escape`, I had added at some point to fix the first encoding problems, pretty much without being able to understand why exactly I need it and what difference it makes.

Now (possibly due to the first occurence of the pound sign), I suddenly got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/module.py", line 135, in _process_web_service_call
    request = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n' + ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 137: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The position 137 here corresponds to the location of the special characters inside the inner XML request. Apparently, cElementTree.tostring() returns a 'str' type, not a 'unicode' even when an encoding is given. So Python tries to decode this string str into unicode (why with 'ascii'?), so that it can concatenate it with the unicode literal. This fails (of course, because the str is actually encoded in UTF-8, not ASCII).

So I figured, fine, I'll decode it to unicode myself then:

```
root = ET.Element(u'ActionCommand')
value = ET.SubElement(root, u'value')
value.text = saxutils.escape(complex_value)
request_encoded_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
request_unicode = request_encoded_str.decode('utf-8')
request = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n' + request_unicode
client.service.ProcessClientAction(request)
```

Except that now, it blows up inside suds, which tries to decode the outer XML request for some reason:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/module.py", line 141, in _process_web_service_call
    raw_response = client.service.ProcessAction(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 643, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in send
    return self.invoke(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 153, in invoke
    u2response = urlopener.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 827, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 565: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The position 565 here again corresponds with the same character as above, except this time it's the location of my inner XML request embedded into the outer XML request (SOAP) created by suds.

I'm confused. Can anyone help me out of this mess? :)

To make matters worse, all of this only happens on the server under Linux. None of these raises an exception in my development environment on Windows. (Bonus points for an explanation as to why that is, just because I'm curious. I suspect it has to do with a different default encoding.) However, they all are not accepted by the server. What does work on Windows is if I drop the `saxutils.escape` and then hand a proper unicode object to suds. This however still results in the same `UnicodeDecodeError` on Linux.

*Update:* I started debugging this on Windows (where it works fine), and in the line 827 of httplib.py, it indeed tries to concatenate the unicode object `msg` (containing the HTTP headers) and the str object `message_body`, leading to the implicit unicode decoding with the incorrect encoding. I guess it just happens to not fail on Windows for some reason. I don't understand why suds tries to send a str object when I put a unicode object in at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be more than absurd. I'm still understanding only small parts of the whole problem and situation, but I managed to solve my problem.

So let's trace it back: my last attempt was the most sane one, I believe. So let's start there:

```
msg += message_body
```

That line in Python's `httplib.py` tries to concatenate a unicode and a str object, which leads to an implicit `.decode('ascii')` of the str, even though the str is UTF8-encoded. Why is that? Because `msg` is a unicode object.

```
msg = "\r\n".join(self._buffer)
```

`self._buffer` is a list of HTTP headers. Inspecting that, only one header in there was unicode, 'infecting' the resulting string: the action and endpoint.

And there's the problem: I'm using `unicode_literals` from `__future__` (makes it more future-proof, right? right???) and I'm passing my own endpoint into suds.

By just doing an `.encode('utf-8')` on the URL, all my problems went away. Even the whole `saxutils.escape` was no longer needed (even though it weirdly also didn't hurt).

**tl;dr**: make sure you're not passing any unicode objects anywhere into httplib or suds, I guess.

```
root = ET.Element(u'ActionCommand')
value = ET.SubElement(root, u'value')
value.text = complex_value)
request = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
client.service.ProcessAction(request)
```